# angular 4 : Multiple *ngFor form container

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a repeated form container and each form having same type of dropdown as ,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of tasks">

  <form name="edit_form_[item.id]">

  ---
    <ul  > ==> custom drop down
      <li *ngFor="let country of countries"> {{county.country_name}} </li>
    </ul>

  ---
  </form>

</div>
```

Since country list is static, it wont change every time, what should be the right way of implementing inner *ngFor. Currently due to this Dom is getting hanging.

(if the parent for loop having 50 -elements, that much of time inner loop also looping. To avoid such inner looping...)

Also I need to add class one country based on parent @ngFor (class="selected")

Please help.

Comment: What's the problem with adding a class?

Comment: Actually no problem with adding class; if the parent for loop having 50 -elements, that much of time inner loop also looping. To avoid such inner looping...

Comment: What do you mean with avoid inner looping? Why did you add the inner `*ngFor` if you don't want it to loop?

Comment: <li *ngFor="let country of countries"> {{county.country_name}} </li> This content is always same for all time except selection(class="selected").. This data is coming from another service. Thanks